# Pass user's session across activities

Tags: android, session-state

What's the best strategy for authenticating users and holding their state throughout an app-run ? So far, I've thought about preferences and, probably, saving state through onSaveInstanceState. I'm not sure whether these approaches are applicable - what would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Application class, this may help you maintain global state variables between activities.